# Mechanistically, how does calcium chloride aid in bacterial transformation?

Tags: biochemistry, bacteriology, biotechnology, plasmids

I am looking to get more information about the mechanism of the $CaCl_2$ in the bacterial transformation. I read online about the topic but I didn't found any reverent information on the topic, I don't have access to most of the scientific publications. However, I found this [website](http://www.madsci.org/posts/archives/2008-08/1219606709.Mb.r.html). According to this website, there is a lot of theory about the mechanism of calcium chloride in the bacterial transformation. Would it be possible to get a short scientific referenced explanation about the topic and I can or cannot be related to heat shocks?

Comment: Frankly, the mechanism is not known even now.

Comment: Duplicate of http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/50591/3340 but the other question is also unanswered.